# Why is this if statement not running when the values are equal to each other?

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement this code which takes Morse code with 3 spaces between each letter and gets the first Morse translation and compares it to an array containing all Morse code translations. Where it goes `buffer == morsem[j]`, the buffer should equal `.-` and `morsem[j]` should also equal `.-`; if `j = 0`, which they both do, but it is not executing `if`'s block. Any idea why?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    char morsem[26][5] = {{".-"},{"-..."},{"-.-."},{"-.."},{"."},{"..-."},{"--."},{"...."},{".."},{".---"},{"-.-"},{".-.."},{"--"},{"-."},{"---"},{".--."},{"--.-"},{".-."},{"..."},{"-"},{"..-"},{"...-"},{".--"},{"-..-"},{"-.--"},{"--.."}};
    char alpha[27] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    char morse[] = ".-   ....";
    int length;
    int first_counter = 0;
    while(morse[first_counter] != '\0'){
        first_counter++;
    }
    char *new_morse = new char [first_counter];
    int counter = 0;

    char *buffer = new char [5];
    for(int x = 0; x < first_counter; x++){
        if(morse[x] != ' '){
            buffer[counter] = morse[x];
            counter++;
        }
        if(morse[x] == ' '&& morse[x+1] == ' ' && morse[x+2] == ' '){
            for(int j=0;j<27;j++){
                if(buffer == morsem[j]){
                    cout << alpha[j] << endl;
                    break;
                }
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < first_counter; i++){
                new_morse[i] = morse[i+x+3];
            }
        }
    }
    delete[] buffer;

    cout << morse << endl;
    cout << new_morse << endl;
}
```

Comment: `buffer == morsem[j]` doesn't do what you think it does. It checks whether two pointers refer to the same location (which they aren't), not whether two locations have the same contents. See `strcmp`. Better still, do yourself a favor and use `std::string` in place of raw character arrays.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik strcmp worked but now the cout statement is printing B instead of an A

Comment: Well, I suppose now would be a good time to learn how to use the debugger.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik `strcmp` won't work here because `buffer` does not contain a null-terminated string

Comment: Its actually working now. I wasnt comparing the result of the strcmp to 0. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`if(buffer == morsem[j]){` is just comparing pointer values and not strings. You need to compare "what the pointers are pointing at".

Since you are in C++, using `std::string` may be easier than char `char` buffers...

Comment: I would be using strings but this is for an assignment that requires me to use char arrays instead. How could I compare the strings and not the pointer values?

Comment: In C you'd use `strcmp()` - you can do that in C++, or look for a more "C++-ish" approach. If you use strcmp read the docs well so you know what the return code means.

Answer (score 1):

if(buffer == morsem[j]), you are just comparing addresses not the content of the address. Use string type than array of character.

Answer (score 0):

You have undefined behaviour in your program, and the fact that your string comparison is wrong only shadows this (more serious) problem.

> ```
> char *buffer = new char [5];
> ```

This creates a dynamic array with 5 `char` elements somewhere in memory, and gives you a pointer to the first of those five elements. Unlike with the static `morsem` array, the elements of the dynamic array created here are **not initialised**. That is, you must not expect them to contain `'\0'` values.

Unlike with string literals, there is also **no null terminator** added automatically. That means when you write `".-"` somewhere in your code, then your compiler treats this as an array with 3 elements: `'.'`, `'-'` and `'\0'`. With dynamic allocation, no such thing happens.

Now, in the following part of your code:

> ```
>     if(morse[x] != ' '){
>         buffer[counter] = morse[x];
>         counter++;
>     }
> ```

`counter` can be 5. But an attempt to access `buffer[5]` is **undefined behaviour**. Since you created `buffer` as a `char[5]`, the only valid indices are 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4. Your program can do anything, including crashing or randomly working fine.

We then have the wrong string comparison:

> ```
>            if(buffer == morsem[j]){
> ```

The problem is that this is no string comparison. You are comparing two pointer values for equality. Use [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) instead.

Now, once you use `strcmp`, the uninitialised `buffer` becomes relevant. `strcmp` requires both arguments to be null-terminated strings. But your code does not guarantee that `buffer[4]` is `'\0'`. This is again undefined behaviour. You probably don't notice it because `morsem[j]` *is* null-terminated, and your implementation's `strcmp` is nice to enough to just stop any comparison as soon as '`\0`' is found in any of the two strings. But that's not a clean solution.

So, in summary, in order to fix all of those problems:

- Understand that the highest index accessible in an array with *N* elements is *N - 1*.
- Understand that allocating a dynamic `char` array leaves you with uninitialised elements and no automatically added `'\0'`.
- Use `strcmp` to compare two `char` arrays lexicographically.

You should also compile with highest warning levels and activate all run-time checks your compiler offers. For example, try the `/MDd` option with Visual C++. It will give you a nice crash (just that the button labels may not be German on your system :)):

[image]

Needless to say that in real code you just use `std::string` and forget all these pointer headaches.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a lot of pointers and I do not see the point (pun not intended). It often leads to confusions and misunderstandings. Personally I'd suggest to avoid using them unless necessary. It's the main problem here because it's comparing pointed to values. Try using the Visual Studio debugger (if you're using Visual Studio) to flush it out. Your use of chars is logical, but be aware that the same result can be achieved with string.